# Spring Tiles Framework : refresh only body content

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Tiles layout page having Header, Menu, Body. In this layout whenever user does some action in the Menu lists, the whole Layout is refreshing. I want header,menu to be static, and only body part should get refresh.

Is there any way to prevent the refresh of the Header, menu and update only Body content on the menu click which can be implemented using Spring Tiles?

I got some same question but its related to structs. i don't have idea about structs 
If anybody give piece of code it will be helpful.

Comment: Use PJAX https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax . Consider SiteMesh over Tiles.

Comment: @Manjunath vibhooti..You got solution above problems...i have same issue .if you find please explain to me.

Comment: @suresh manda Not yet man

Comment: @ManjunathVibhooti: I am also looking for the same solution.Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(1)write this tiles configuration into spring xml file.
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"/>

        <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/views.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

(2)layouts.xml file 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC  
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"  
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="DefaultTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/views/template/SiteTemplate.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title"     value="Home" />
        <put-attribute name="header"    value="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu"      value="/WEB-INF/views/template/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body"      value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer"    value="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>

(3)views.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="index" extends="DefaultTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="body"  value="/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="personList" extends="DefaultTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="body"  value="/WEB-INF/views/personList.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>

(4)SiteTemplate.jsp

    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Spring MVC - Tiles Integration tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"></link>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
        <![endif]-->
    <style>
    body{ margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#DFDFDF;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="border: #C1C1C1 solid 1px; border-radius:10px;">
            <!-- Header -->
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
            <!-- Menu Page -->
            <div class="span-5  border" style="height:400px;background-color:#FCFCFC;">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
            </div>
            <!-- Body Page -->
            <div class="span-19 last">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
            </div>
            <!-- Footer Page -->
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

(5)menu.jsp

    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <ul style="list-style:none;line-height:28px;">

        <li><spring:url value="/index" var="homeUrl" htmlEscape="true" />
            <a href="${homeUrl}">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li><spring:url value="/viewPeson" var="personListUrl" htmlEscape="true" />
            <a href="${personListUrl}">Person List</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

(6)same as write footer.jsp and header.jsp for your requirement.

(7)code for controlller

    @RequestMapping(value="index")
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }
**NOTE:return type value is same as definition name in views.xml**
```

Comment: I did't get what you are saying...   if i do what you said still it refreshing the whole page ... did you understood my problem sanjay

Comment: anyway thanks sanjay .. it explain only about tiles ... i have different problem please read question again